# Is this crash caused by me or UIKit itself?

Tags: ios, crash, uikit, crash-reports

This crash report is really tough for me to get a handle on. I've seen it every now and then, and its been pretty impossible to fix given that it doesn't really give me any references to my code to work from.

Is this a crash that was caused by Apple and I don't have to worry about it?

```
Date/Time:       2013-02-26 03:49:36 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x33973d24
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x33973d24 CFRetain + 8
1   UIKit                               0x359484f9 -[UIKeyboardCache displayView:imageWidth:withKey:fromLayout:] + 297
2   UIKit                               0x359483c7 -[UIKeyboardCache displayView:withKey:fromLayout:] + 91
3   UIKit                               0x35947b5b -[UIKBKeyplaneView displayLayer:] + 191
4   QuartzCore                          0x355f34f7 CA::Layer::display() + 95
5   QuartzCore                          0x355ea93b CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 203
6   QuartzCore                          0x355ea865 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 25
7   QuartzCore                          0x355ea243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 239
8   QuartzCore                          0x355ea051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 317
9   QuartzCore                          0x355e9eb1 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 61
10  CoreFoundation                      0x33a096cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
11  CoreFoundation                      0x33a079c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 277
12  CoreFoundation                      0x33a07d17 __CFRunLoopRun + 743
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3397aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3397ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
15  GraphicsServices                    0x3753c2eb GSEventRunModal + 75
16  UIKit                               0x35890301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
17  MyApp                               0x0004e60f main (main.m:16)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbbc648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3bae7df8 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 36

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbbbeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33a09045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33a07da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3397aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3397ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x3996f505 RunWebThread(void*) + 445
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbbbeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33a09045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33a07da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3397aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3397ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x3429df97 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 255
6   Foundation                          0x34341865 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   MyApp                               0x0003f7b5 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:161)
8   Foundation                          0x3434ae85 __NSThread__main__ + 973
9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbbbeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33a09045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33a07da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3397aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3397ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x342c73d5 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x3434ae85 __NSThread__main__ + 973
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbcc594 __select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbcc08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb1daa5 pthread_cond_timedwait + 45
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x37932c75 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 109
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x37a44557 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 83
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x37a56fab WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbbbeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33a09045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33a07da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3397aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3397ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   AudioToolbox                        0x3345c703 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 139
6   AudioToolbox                        0x3343d885 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 297
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb25311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbccd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb1aa16 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3bbccd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3bb1aa16 _pthread_wqthread + 366
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

This is not caused by apple. Below line is the entry point of the crash. Make sure some related object/view  doesn't get deallocated.

```
 MyApp    0x0003f7b5 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:161
```

Update:

I take back my object deallocation statement. I doubt this crash might happen due to UI element being created\updated in background thread. I mean an UI element created/updated in the network callback method.

The solution to the problem would be adding a `dispatch_async` in `main_queue` to perform the UI updates.

Comment: The crash report states the problem is on thread 0. What you pointed out is from thread 3. How can this be the entry point of the crash?

Comment: @rmaddy I said its the starting point. I did not say its crashing at thread 3. The call made on a different thread causes a crash when it reaches the main thread. What I assume, is the autorelease pool of the thread3 is drained.

Comment: How does a call on a different thread reach the main thread? What do you mean by that?

Comment: When the thread ends eventually. Or probably UI is updated from the thread.

Comment: Considering that AFNetworking starts that thread and its running the entire time the app is running I highly doubt this is the case. I have had issues where a network callback gets sent to a deallocated object and it doesn't look like this. I would see in the main thread (where the network library does callbacks to my app) something like [NetworkHandler didfinishconnection] from my app and then a crash.